# Hack-A-Rank not accepting mod(column, 2) = 0;

Tags: sql, mysql

I may be being stupid but i have tried multiple iterations and none seem to accept the MOD function to only get even ID numbers, no i cannot see the actual database as its apart of the challenge

any help would be greatly appreciated :)

```
SELECT CITY 
FROM STATION 
WHERE mod(ID, 2) = 0;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read the complete challenge description. You are missing a `distinct`.

> Query a list of CITY names from STATION for cities that have an even ID number. Print the results in any order, **but exclude duplicates from the answer**.

```
SELECT distinct CITY FROM STATION WHERE mod(ID, 2) = 0;
```